# Create new user in database but keep password if it exists in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, updates

I am wondering if the `updateOrCreate` method in Laravel has a way to skip some information in case the record exists in the database. For example, I wanna be able to search for users, and assign a password if the user is to be created, but not if the user already exists.

Say, I have 3 data for a user, $email, $info and $password. The search criteria would of course be $email, then maybe $info needs to be updated for whatever reason, while $password should only be given if the record is new.

Is there a 'do not update' parameter for updateOrCreate where I can put the password?

```
User::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'email'    => $email  // These parameters are the search criteria, but also used on create
    ],
    [
        'data'     => $info,  // These parameters are the values that will be updated if exist
    ],
    [
        'password' => $password, // These parameters are used only in create but are not search criteria
    ]
);
```

Comment: No, `updateOrCreate` literally just uses `firstOrNew` and then `fill` under the hood. Is the password randomly generated?

Comment: Split it up in Create and Update and test the conditions first. The `users` table is a special case. Do not create loopholes. I guess you must have 2 'users' tables, because that's the only possibility for a scenario you are describing.

Comment: No, for new users in the company we use the document number the first time, then they are asked to change it as soon as they log in the system. So, if I use the update for that field, they will loose the password they gave

Comment: Does the first login also change the username or is the username set (doc nr)? Maybe have a look at 'upsert' https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#upserts 
If the doc nr is purely integer, maybe you could use it as the id of the `users` table. Maybe a bit unconventional, but one piece of information you already know for sure.

Comment: you could macro your own updateOrCreate type method that does what you need for you

Answer (score 0):

There are so many questions I would have love to ask to fully understand your organization's process.
1.How did the information get to the db at the first place if the user has not be created?
2. Why can't the password be generated when creating the info into the db at the first place
But I guess all these might bore down to design issue so, I think would say you can create a regular expression that would match your organization document number pattern and use it to check for new user through a loop and the assign password to such ones.